# Bounding a function times the mean of the reciprocal

Tags: integration, inequality, periodic-functions, means, elementary-functions

My question might be trivial.  Can one characterize all the periodic regular functions $f:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, say for symplicity $f\geq1$, such that
$$f(x)\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{f(y)}dy\leq 2\pi?$$

Comment: what is a regular function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f$ must be a constant function.
Namely, the regular positive function $\varphi(x) := 1/f(x)$ must satisfy
$$
\varphi(x) \geq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \varphi(y)\, dy
\qquad
\forall x\in [-\pi, \pi],
$$
i.e. $\varphi$ must be $\geq$ its integral mean at every point.
But this can happen if and only if $\varphi$ is constant.

Comment: cant $\varphi(x)$ take larger values in a set of measure $0$?

Comment: The OP asked for a regular function (I've assumed that regular means at least continuous).

Comment: haha ok, seems legit. +1

Comment: yes regular= at least continuous

Comment: trivial indeed, better to stop for today :)